# EC2 NGINX 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, 301-redirect

I'm managing two domains `domainA.com` and `domainB.com` on DNS Made Easy. Both domains point to the same EC2 instance.

`domainA` had a HTTP redirection record for `www.domainA.com` to `domainA.com`, that record was deleted and replaced by a CNAME record for `www.domainA.com` to `domainA.com`.

`domainB.com` has a CNAME record for `www.domainB.com` to `domainB.com`.

When I go to `http://domainB.com` the page loads correctly, but when I go to `http://www.domainB.com` I get redirected to `https://www.domainA.com`, notice the secure protocol here!

My first thought was that the HTTP redirection record for `domainA.com` was being cached, but the guys at DNS Made Easy pointed out that executing `$ curl -I http://www.domainB.com` returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://domainA.com/
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.53
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 19:21:41 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.53
```

So I looked in NGINX's `sites-available` directory for any HTTP redirects configured on `domainA.com`and `domainB.com`

`domainA` looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domainA.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domainA.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

  root /webapps/domainA/current/public;
  server_name domainA.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
}
```

And `domainB` looks like the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /webapps/domainB/current/public;
  server_name domainB.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
}
```

Nothing there, so then I thought to look in AWS but Route 53 is not even setup!

So now I'm really out of ideas, and I'm a web developer so server stuff is not really my strong suite so any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: The "Powered by phusion passenger" header suggests that this could be a misconfiguration in passenger.

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if you posted the actual domain names. I'm surprised it returns anything as you haven't listed the www subdomains in the nginx configuration. Add debugging to your location blocks to see what it's hitting - see how with add_header in this answer [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/747143/nginx-gzip-static-removes-content-encoding-header/747201#747201)

Comment: So I read the Passenger docs for my setup and they suggest that when you are testing with curl and you don't see the expected HTML to check the `server_name` directive. Changing that from `domainB.com` to `domainB.com www.domainB.com` solved the issue. Thanks @DerfK

Comment: Well then I'll put it as an answer so you can mark it as correct then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the subdomains to the server_name directive (as per comments).